# Big O in probability through Chernoff bound

Tags: probability

Let sample $X_1, \ldots, X_{n^2} \sim $ Bernoulli($p$) independently. The true probability $p$ can be estimated as
$$
\hat p = \sum_{i = 1}^{n^2} X_i / n^2.
$$
Then it is claimed that a simple application of the Chernoff bound gives 
$$
\sqrt{\hat p (1 - \hat p)} = \sqrt{p (1 - p)} (1 + O_P(1 / n)).
$$
Does anyone know how to prove this? I am not very familiar with Chernoff bound, it doesn't seem simple to me.

The notation $O_P(\cdot)$ is order in probability([Big O in probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_in_probability_notation)).

$X_n = O_P(a_n)$ means the set of values $X_n/a_n$ is stochastically bounded. That is, for any $ε > 0$, there exists a finite $M > 0$ and a finite $N > 0$ such that,
$$
{\displaystyle P(|X_{n}/a_{n}|>M)<\varepsilon ,\;\forall \;n>N.}
$$

Chernoff bound definition gives this: $X = \sum_{i =1}^{n^2} X_i$, then
$$
P(|X - n^2 p| \geq \delta n^2 p) \leq 2 e^{- n^2 p \delta^2 / 3} \ \text{ for all } \ \delta \in (0, 1).
$$
It follows that
$$
P(|\hat p -  p| \geq \delta p) \leq 2 e^{- n^2 p \delta^2 / 3}.\\
$$
Then
$$
(\hat p - p) / p = O_P(n^{-1}).\\
\hat p = p (1 + O_P(1 / n)).
$$
However, they are $\sqrt{\hat p (1 - \hat p)} $ and $ \sqrt{p (1 - p)}$ instead of $\hat p$ and $p$ in my question.

Comment: By similar argument you can have $1-\hat{p} = (1-p)(1+O_P(1/n))$.  Combine it with $\hat{p} = p(1+O_P(1/n))$, I think it's basically the proof.

Comment: @Fang-YiYu: Thanks for your quick reply! Does this mean $\hat p (1 - \hat p) = p (1 - p) (1 + O_P(1 / n))^2$, then the result is obtained by taking square root on both sides?

Comment: Yes, though, there may be some work to formalize this.

Comment: @Fang-YiYu Thank you very much for your help!